# Passing php array for use in javascript using json_encode

Tags: php, javascript, json

I know this has been asked plenty of times before but still I have a problem after readaing all the other posts on the subject... Somewhere between my php code -and the javascript it is sitting in- my array is going awol.

In the attached code, I have an echo for debugging of the php. When I cut out the php section from the javascript and run it separately with the echo on, it shows me that it is building my json_encoded array correctly.

In the javascript immediately after the php end I assign the php to a javascript variable, so I can use it for further processing (plotting a graph). Putting in display statements, to display the content of the result of the php call to get the array into javascript, shows the array is empty.

If I cut and paste the output of the php echo and assign this literal to the javascript chartData array then everything works fine. Why is the javascript not getting the php array content?

Here's the code snip:

```
<script>
...some java script stuff;
<?php
// Define the mySQL db connection
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=remets;charset=UTF-8', 'remets', 'remets',         array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
// Define SQL query to fetch data from mySQL
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT WeekNumber,XAxisCategory,YAxisValue FROM Metric WHERE ReportID = 'Q3' ORDER BY WeekNumber,XAxisCategory ASC");

                                // declarations
                                $amData = array();
                                $amArray = array();
                                $ctrinner = 0;
                                $ctrouter = -1;
                                $prevweek = "9999";

                                // Fetch data from mySQL and put it in an array in the format we need
                                while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                    if ($prevweek !== $row['WeekNumber']) {
                                        $ctrouter++;
                                        $ctrinner = 0;
                                        $amData[$ctrouter]["week"] = "".$row['WeekNumber'];  // Prepending (or appending) the empty string makes the json encoding think the week number is a string, which is MUST have for AmCharts
                                  }
                                    $ctrinner++;
                                    $amData[$ctrouter][$row['XAxisCategory']] = $row['YAxisValue'];
                                    $prevweek = $row['WeekNumber'];
                                }

                                    // Using json_encode puts the data into an array format that we can use in a javascript
                                    $amJSONArray = json_encode($amData);

                                    // Echo is for debugging only.
                                    // echo $amJSONArray;


                            ?>

                            var chartData = <?php echo $amJSONArray; 
?>;

...more javascript stuff;

</script>
```

@Mahdi: The output of the print_r is: Array ( [0] => Array ( [week] => 1301 [Accepted] => 30 [Failed] => 5 [Passed] => 20 [Planned] => 5 [Skipped] => 5 [Unknown] => 26 ) [1] => Array ( [week] => 1302 [Accepted] => 25 [Failed] => 2 [Passed] => 25 [Planned] => 2 [Skipped] => 3 [Unknown] => 20 ) [2] => Array ( [week] => 1303 [Accepted] => 26 [Failed] => 26 [Passed] => 29 [Planned] => 26 [Skipped] => 26 [Unknown] => 10 ) )

@Mahdi: This is the jscript code immediately after the php (It is commented out because I tried lots of different options that were recommended in other posts in this forum and others - none of them work. I can run the php code and that works fine. If I copy the output of the echo in the php code snip I posted earlier and simply assign that to chartData (ie: chartData = ""; 
my chart is produced fine. The problem is not with the charting tool but somehow the array content is just not visible to the javascript which is directly below it in the .js file.
Thanks for your time up til now.

```
                            //var chartData = "<?php print($amJSONArray); ?>";  // This just returns the literal in the speech marks
                            //var chartData = '<?php print($amJSONArray); ?>';  // This also returns the literal in the speech marks
                            //var chartData = "<?php echo($amJSONArray); ?>";   // This just returns the literal in the speech marks
                            //var chartData = '<?php echo($amJSONArray); ?>';   // This also returns the literal in the speech marks
                            //var chartData = <?php echo ($amJSONArray) ?>;     // This returns empty
                            //var chartData = <?php echo $amJSONArray ?>;       // This returns empty
                            //var chartData = (<?php echo $amJSONArray ?>);     // This returns empty
                            //alert(chartData);                                                                 // Returns empty - just showing the contents of the array if I do the json_encode within the php part
                            //alert(<?php echo $amJSONArray ?>);                                // Returns empty - just showing the contents of the array if I do the json_encode during the array fetch
```

UPDATE:
I think there's something fundamentally wrong going on at my side. I used a very simple example which should write "hello world" to the screen but it returns nothing at all. If I substitute the 'write' with an 'alert' then it still shows nothing in the alert popup. Does anyone know why this would not be working? The code is:

```
<?php
   $testvar = "Hello World";
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hello()
 {
   // create JavaScript variable, fill it with Php variable
   var testvar = "<? print $testvar; ?>";
  // output to screen

   document.write( testvar );   
 } 
</script>
</head>

<!-- Call JavaScript function to display variable -->
<body onload="hello()" >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, you think the _encoded_ JSON in `$amJSONArray` is a string?

Comment: No, it's an array containing 1 character per row. If I change the echo to echo $amJSONArray[<indexnumber>]; it displays the character at that row (correctly).

Comment: `print_r($amData)` to see what you have there ... if you see one `char` per row, but it supposed to be an `Array`, it means that you have assigned a `String` instead of an `Array` ...

Comment: From the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), `string json_encode ( mixed $value [, int $options = 0 ] )` .. `json_encode` will definitely return a string, meaning the line should be `var chartData = '<?php echo $amJSONArray ?>';` .. and echoing a string with `$string[1]` will display the second char of that string, `$string[0]` will display the first char .. this has nothing to do with `$amJSONArray` being of type `array` ..

Comment: OK, I assumed the type was array because I could address it using an index as per an array. The output of the php echo command is: [{"week":"1301","Accepted":30,"Failed":5,"Passed":20,"Planned":5,"Skipped":5,"Unknown":26},{"week":"1302","Accepted":25,"Failed":2,"Passed":25,"Planned":2,"Skipped":3,"Unknown":20},{"week":"1303","Accepted":26,"Failed":26,"Passed":29,"Planned":26,"Skipped":26,"Unknown":10}]

Comment: ...and this is exactly what it should look like in my js variable chartData, which should be an array. It could be that what the echo is showing me is a string but I pass a php array into the json_encode.

Comment: @Mahdi: The output of the print_r is: Array ( [0] => Array ( [week] => 1301 [Accepted] => 30 [Failed] => 5 [Passed] => 20 [Planned] => 5 [Skipped] => 5 [Unknown] => 26 ) [1] => Array ( [week] => 1302 [Accepted] => 25 [Failed] => 2 [Passed] => 25 [Planned] => 2 [Skipped] => 3 [Unknown] => 20 ) [2] => Array ( [week] => 1303 [Accepted] => 26 [Failed] => 26 [Passed] => 29 [Planned] => 26 [Skipped] => 26 [Unknown] => 10 ) )

Comment: I don't know which chart you're using and what is the proper data format for that chart, however you can simply access the sample data like this `console.log(chartData[0].week);`. It seems your php output is okay, but you have problem in the javascript side. It will be good if you post some of the related javascript code as well ...

Comment: Strings are similar to char arrays in most languages, that is why you can access the characters by their index.

Comment: Thanks for adding in an update as to what the problem was. However, questions are not the right place for that, so I've rolled that edit back. Would you kindly copy your update ([from here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16131220/revisions)) and paste it into an answer? (As I said in a comment elsewhere, `.html` files are not passed through the PHP engine by default deliberately, so this is not a bug).

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to access the data as a string, you can try using the built-in `JSON.parse()` to convert it into usable javascript.

Comment: Maybe I'm completely missing the point of the json_encode. I thought I needed json_encode as a way to get the array back to javascript so I can use it with amcharts. Amcharts expects a json_encoded array (and this works if I copy+paste the output of the php echo statement when I run the php code on its own). The whole problem seems to be the handover of the array from the php to the js code. In php all is fine but I am struggling with how to get the contents of that array back into javascript so I can pass it as a parameter to amcharts. It's probably something so obvious and simple.

Comment: the PHP json_encode passes data as JSON, not as javascript. it is essentially represented as a **string**, so that's why it requires the JSON.parse javascript function to interpret it as javascript.